# Drop Shadow Cropped, Overflow:visible isn't working

Tags: css

I've got the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="boxy"><img><p>Paragraph testing.</p></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.boxy{
    width= 150px;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90);
    opacity:0.9;
    color: #e9e9e9;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", arial, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 5px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

I notice that on jsfiddle the div appears long although I've limited it by width. I've also added Overflow:Visible but did not work. Would appreciate any advise. Thanks!

Comment: You haven't added any `box-shadow` into your css.

Comment: I have added that... thanks! however the top and bottom seems cropped out

Comment: I've changed from "margin:0 auto" to "margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px" and it looks fine! thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
width= 150px;
```

To this:

```
width: 150px;
```

Comment: That's a silly mistake on my part! However this time the top and bottom seems cropped out. I've changed from "margin:0 auto" to "margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px" and it looks fine! thanks very much!